# Как добавить CSS флажок на картинку?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, градиент

Помогите пожалуйста нарисовать флажок на картинке. Знаю, что это можно сделать с помощью `linear-gradient()`, получилось примерно так

```css
div {
 width: 270px;
 height: 270px;
 background-image: linear-gradient(230deg, #000 17px, transparent 12px), linear-gradient(310deg, #000 17px, transparent 12px);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 30px 30px;
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
   <div></div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Но как добавить белые полоски?

[image: Картинка с флажком]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.b-picture{
  background: url('https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/WxoUgse8zWBhqaUKnC7s9w/ls.jpg') no-repeat 0 0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
}
.b-ribbon{
  position: absolute; bottom: 15px; right: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 60px;  
  overflow: hidden;
}
.b-ribbon:before,
.b-ribbon:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; right: -10px;
  background: #c00;
  width: 40px;
  height: 30px;  
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.b-ribbon:before{
  top: 0;   
  -webkit-transform: skew(35deg);
  transform: skew(35deg);
}
.b-ribbon:after{
  top: 30px;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-35deg);
  transform: skew(-35deg);
}

.b-ribbon > span{}
.b-ribbon > span:before,
.b-ribbon > span:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; right: -7px;
  width:100%;
  height: 4px;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
}
.b-ribbon > span:before{
  top: 10px;     
  -webkit-transform: skew(35deg);
  transform: skew(35deg);
}
.b-ribbon > span:after{    
  bottom: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-35deg);
  transform: skew(-35deg);
}
.b-ribbon:hover:before,
.b-ribbon:hover:after{
  background: #00f;
}
```

```html
<div class="b-picture">
<div class="b-ribbon"><span></span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: а можно ли как-то этот флажок увеличить? чтобы хорошо смотрелось и на изображении 270px x 270px

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/d2c2yso2/